# Counting the degrees of planets using pyswisseph, why is it not correct

Tags: python

there is a code for calculating the degrees of the planets relative to the Earth according to astrological rules:
We take the time for the beginning of the desired day and for the beginning of the next day, we subtract the next one from the desired one, we get how much the planet has passed in a day, if the value is negative, then its movement is retrograde and we mark it with the letter "R".

Next, we need how much the planet passed in a second, for this we divide the distance that the planet passed in a day by 24 hours and 3600 seconds, we get how much the planet passed in 1 second that day.

The resulting value is multiplied by the number of seconds of the required time.

For example, we need to find the time 11:35 in Moscow, it's utc+3, so we take 3 hours from 11:35, we get 8:35 translated into seconds, 8h= 8x3600=28800+35x60=30900 seconds
multiply this time by the value that the planet passed in 1 second that day.
Next, add this value to the value at the beginning of the day and you're done. If the movement is retrograde, then we take it away.

```py
import swisseph as swe

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

from app.services.time_convert import get_julian_datetime

# Загрузка переменных окружения из файла .env
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

# Установка пути к эфемеридам
swe.set_ephe_path(os.getenv('EPH_PATH'))


class Planets:
    def __init__(self, year: int, month: int, day: int, hour: int, minute: int, timezone: int) -> None:
        """
Constructor of the Planets class. Accepts parameters for object initialization.

        :params year: 
        :params month: 
        :params day: 
        :params hour: 
        :params minute: 
        :params timezone: UTC time zone offset in HH format
        """
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute
        self.second = 0
        self.timezone = timezone
        



    def get_planet_positions(self):
        planet_names = {
            swe.SUN: "Sun",
            swe.MOON: "Moon",
            swe.MERCURY: "Mercury",
            swe.VENUS: "Venus",
            swe.MARS: "Mars",
            swe.JUPITER: "Jupiter",
            swe.SATURN: "Saturn",
            swe.URANUS: "Uranus",
            swe.NEPTUNE: "Neptune",
            swe.PLUTO: "Pluto",
            swe.MEAN_NODE: "Mean Node",
            swe.TRUE_NODE: "True Node"
        }
        
        
        julian_day_start = swe.julday(self.year, self.month, self.day, 0, 0)  
        julian_day_next = swe.julday(self.year, self.month, self.day + 1, 0, 0)  
        
        time = ((self.hour - self.timezone) * 3600) + (self.minute) * 60

        planet_positions = {}
        
        for planet_id, planet_name in planet_names.items():

            planet_position_start = swe.calc_ut(julian_day_start, planet_id)[0][0]
            planet_position_next = swe.calc_ut(julian_day_next, planet_id)[0][0]
            
            planet_24_distance = planet_position_next - planet_position_start
            planet_disctance_per_second = planet_24_distance / 86400

            if planet_24_distance < 0:
                planet_motion = " R"
                end_planet_position = planet_position_start - (time * planet_disctance_per_second)
            else:
                planet_motion = ""
                end_planet_position = planet_position_start + (time * planet_disctance_per_second)
            
            planet_positions[planet_name] = f"{end_planet_position}{planet_motion}"
        
        return planet_positions
```

The timezone is considered a separate function:

```py
# app/services/time_convert.py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder
import math
import pytz

def get_time_zone(latitude: float, longitude: float) -> int:
    """
    Getting the UTC time zone in HH format

    :params latitude: 
    :params longitude: 

    :returns: Offset Hour
    """
    tf = TimezoneFinder()
    timezone_str = tf.timezone_at(lng=longitude, lat=latitude)

    if timezone_str is None:
        return None
    
    now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(timezone_str))
    utc_offset = int(now.utcoffset().total_seconds() / 3600)

    return utc_offset
```

When you run the script to count the planets by selecting the date 2002, 1, 1, 00, 00. UTC+03:00 issues:
Sun: 293.5054715434684
Moon: 297.0847613189008
Mercury: 312.33379667722687
Venus: 293.3607665555996
Mars: 356.29460076953967
Jupiter: 98.9262063073128 R
Saturn: 68.60517297323375 R
Uranus: 323.0939618407774
Neptune: 307.9072550628026
Pluto: 256.47708428413205
Mean Node: 85.66235488484487 R
True Node: 87.05647582717305 R

Despite astro.com it
turns out this:
https://www.astro.com/cgi/swetest.cgi?b=1.1.2002&n...

What is my mistake?